# How to apply CSS changes in order?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I sometimes come across cases where I want to apply several changes to the CSS in immediate succession, making sure that each one is registered by the renderer.

[Here's a simplified example](https://codepen.io/Tobl/pen/KrAYrm)

The height of the element is auto, so it can't be transitioned from. So I'd want to set the elements height to the current computed height and then immediately change the class to start the transition. If that happens in the next line of code, the css-renderer doesn't have time to react to the first change and it is as if only the class was changed -> no transition.

```
var foo = $(".foo");
foo[0].addEventListener("click", function(ev){
  foo.css({"height":foo.height()+"px"});
  foo.addClass("active");
});  //this doesn't work, foo.css…' is ignored.
```

We can delay to the smallest animatable timestep with `window.requestAnimationFrame()`, however, due to browser differences these already need two nested calls to support Firefox.

```
var dan = $(".dan");
dan[0].addEventListener("click", function(ev){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    dan.css({"height":dan.height()+"px"});
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      dan.addClass("active");
    });
  });
});  //this does work (afai can tell), but feels overdone with all that nesting.
```

Technically, this code works. I'm just wondering if this is really the best way to chain css changes like this or if there are other methods.

Comment: This is a great question. Looking at the example given, the webkit transitions are not present in the code. Although I don't think that would solve your problem its worth putting them in to see how it reacts.

Comment: transitions are prefix-less on all current browsers, so while they're still necessary in production, it doesn't impact this question. Updated the code anyway and doesn't show any difference in behavior.

Comment: I assumed there should be an easy answer to this, but I guess not. I think there may be a way to do it using the jQuery `.queue` but I wasn't able to get it working in a few min of fiddling, so I'll throw that out here so someone else might be able to figure it out. I believe the old way was with a setInterval or setTimeout, but that would make your transition potentially pause before acting and wouldn't be any prettier in code.

Comment: Where's `Application.DoEvents()` when you need it?

Comment: Please consider updating this question to remove the "best" indication, or to indicate what "best" and "better" mean exactly. For instance, you could mean "fewer lines of code" or "faster performance", but we don't know.

Comment: Also, in general, the solution to animating height when an element's height is unknown is to use the `max-height` property. But I feel that isn't really the heart of the question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I meant the same 'best' as in 'best practices', but I added a short paragraph to clarify.

Comment: So, the problem is that doesn't help. Questions which are "primarily opinion based" are off-topic on Stack Overflow. See the [help/dont-ask]. There is a close reason which states: *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Comment: @JustH you're right, this is really just one example for the general problem of making the renderer acknowledge css-changes before continuing. Personally, I usually avoid the animate-max-height "solution" since you always end up hardcoding an estimate of what kind of height should be supported. And if you're off, either the element doesn't fully expand or the transition's easing-curve is mangled.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This isn't "what's your favorite code editor" this is a very specific question about how to solve a particular problem in CSS. But if "best practice"-questions aren't allowed here and this is considered one: Where else should this be discussed, that has the same kind of knowledge pool as SO (since even here answers are rather thin) and that is centered around programmers of all experiences helping each other? If you can point me there, I'll happily move camp.

Comment: @Tobl, again, if you amend the question to only ask "How do I solve this problem?" there wouldn't be an issue. Hence why I asked you to "consider updating this question" to remove the references about the "best" way of doing it, rather than simply "a" way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` here to ensure that the class change always happens after the `height` of the `div` is computed.

**Example:**

```js
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName('foo')[0];
var bar = document.getElementsByClassName('bar')[0];
var dan = document.getElementsByClassName('dan')[0];

function fooFunction(element) {
    element.style.height = element.clientHeight + 'px';

    setTimeout(function(){
        element.classList.add('active');
        element.removeAttribute('style');
    },10);

}

foo.addEventListener('click',function(){fooFunction(foo);},false);
bar.addEventListener('click',function(){fooFunction(bar);},false);
dan.addEventListener('click',function(){fooFunction(dan);},false);
```

```css
.foo, .bar, .dan{
width:20%;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
vertical-align:top;
transition: height 1s ease-out;
}

.active {
height:50px;
}

.foo {
background:rgb(150, 100, 100);
}

.bar {
background:rgb(150, 150, 100);
}

.dan {
background:rgb(100, 150, 100);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
<p>Works.</p>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph. This one is even longer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, fugiat facere? Animi, odit et tempore debitis modi quae eaque, libero, dolores magni, voluptas tenetur tempora quidem alias ut praesentium sed.</p>
</div>

<div class="bar">
<p>Works.</p>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph. This one is even longer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, fugiat facere? Animi, odit et tempore debitis modi quae eaque, libero, dolores magni, voluptas tenetur tempora quidem alias ut praesentium sed.</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph. This one is even longer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, fugiat facere? Animi, odit et tempore debitis modi quae eaque, libero, dolores magni, voluptas tenetur tempora quidem alias ut praesentium sed.</p>
</div>

<div class="dan">
<p>Works.</p>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
<p>Third paragraph. This one is even longer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, fugiat facere? Animi, odit et tempore debitis modi quae eaque, libero, dolores magni, voluptas tenetur tempora quidem alias ut praesentium sed.</p>
<p>Fourth paragraph. This one is even longer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, fugiat facere? Animi, odit et tempore debitis modi quae eaque, libero, dolores magni, voluptas tenetur tempora quidem alias ut praesentium sed.</p>
<p>Fifth paragraph. This one is even longer. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, fugiat facere? Animi, odit et tempore debitis modi quae eaque, libero, dolores magni, voluptas tenetur tempora quidem alias ut praesentium sed.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That does work (as it says in the divs) and it does get rid of one of the nesting levels. Are the 10ms just "long enough for the renderer to notice, short enough that humans won't", or is there something specific about that number? Are there other advantages to using this method besides the flatter code?

Comment: There's nothing special about the `10ms` delay. It's, just as you correctly surmise, intended to be long enough to ensure the height has definitely been computed, but short enough, that humans won't see a noticeable difference before the animation begins.

Comment: You can get rid of _two_ nesting levels by adding a common class to `foo`, `bar` and `dan`, grabbing the `NodeList` and then adding the event listener to each node in the `NodeList`, using a `for loop`.

Comment: The other advantage (that I can immediately think of) is that it's javascript, rather than jQuery. Some will say that doesn't really constitute an advantage. Each to their own.

Comment: re:nesting: I don't see how you would save two nesting levels. It would still be nodeList[i]->clickHandler->timeoutCallback as opposed to elem->clickHandler->animationFrameCallback->animationFrameCallback, only one level flatter. (I didn't even notice your additional level with the anonymous function in the addEventListener before)

Comment: re:js-jquery: I definitely see value in jquery-less solutions, especially when it comes to generalizable questions. But the jquery in the old solution was really just fluff, the driving window.requestAnimationFrame is pure js.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know the height of the target elements before the click event, just check it after the DOM is ready and set each of the target elements to it's own height.
in this way, when you will click on a target element:
*the animation will work because the element's height is already set.
*there will be one less command to execute on the click event.

if you'r already work with jQuery, you can use it all the way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // use document ready so we can get the target elements height after they finished to load. 
    var $tran = $('.transition'); // get "transition" class. instead of using different class name for each element, i use unique class for the animation part, the change needs to be on the HTML and CSS too of course, you will see it in the example. 
    $tran.each(function(){ // run each loop so we can get each of the elements that have the class "transition", this is important when the elements height different from each other.
        var height = $(this).height(); // get the height of the current element in the loop. 
        $(this).height(height); // set the height of the current element in the loop. 
    });
    $tran.click(function(){ // set jQuery click event
        $(this).addClass('active'); // add the "active" class
    });
});
```

vanilla:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ // use DOMContentLoaded so we can get the target elements height after they finished to load.
  var tran = document.getElementsByClassName('transition'); // get "transition" class.
  for ( let i = 0; i <= tran.length-1; i++ ){ // run for loop so we can get each of the elements that have the class "transition", this is important when the elements height different from each other.
    let height = tran[i].clientHeight; // get the height of the current element in the loop. 
    tran[i].style.height = height + 'px'; // set the height of the current element in the loop. 
    tran[i].addEventListener("click", function(ev){ // set click event
      this.className = this.className + " active"; // add the "active" class 
    });
  }
});
```

each of the target elements got the transition class:

```
<div class="foo transition">
...
<div class="bar transition">
...  
<div class="dan transition">
...
```

the transition part move into it's own class so you can remove the class from the HTML later if you decide the drop it or use it for another elements.
it's not on the "active" class anymore so it's effecting the elements without a connection to the click event, in this way you can use for example `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()` and you will get an "opening up" animating when clicking again on the elements:

```
.foo, .bar, .dan {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.transition {
  -webkit-transition: height 1000ms;
  transition: height 1000ms;
}
.active {
  height: 50px !important;
}
```

live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/84joouov/
*in the example i let you choose from using pure JS to jQuery by setting the "use_jquery" variable to true or false.

Comment: This breaks down as soon as the element's height changes for any reason. That is why the example used %-width, you can see it in your own demo if you resize the browser before clicking.

Comment: well, i didn't understand from the question that you'r looking for responsive, i thought that this are the only situations...you can use resize() function for example if you want to get the new height on window width change...

Comment: onResize adds far more load and doesn't catch all reasons for resizing. For example what if the div contains a child that can change height? That's why I asked about this very specific part of the implementation.